# Can't find element using by.XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, element

I'm trying to find one element using Selenium in Python using the following code:

`element_A = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/i')`

in this HTML code:

```html
<div class="display-flex>
        <span class=" cc-customer-info__value"="">212121 <i title="copiar" class="fa fa-clone _clipboard_" data-clipboard="212121 "></i> <br>
      </div>
```

I want the number 212121, but I'm getting no such element error. The problem is this number can be different every time that I open the website. It's the number of the customer.
Is it possible to help me to locate this element?

I'm also trying to find two more elements:

Customer profile, it's also change

```html
<text class="legend-graph font-menu" x="416" y="38">Customer Profile: A</text>
```

and Diamond, that also can vary

```html
<span class="cc-customer-info__value ">Diamond</span>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Share the URL you are working with. That'll be the best!

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, the span element has the text as number, not the  tag.

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span)

try this it may work, or try to shorten the xpath you are creating. this is absolute xpath.
try and use selenium ide to record the scenario and check what locator is being captured for the element.
you could also try devtools/ and other xpath locating tools which are available as chrome extentions.

Comment: Do you know any tool to recommend me?

Comment: try the devtools of the browser itself first, and you can try selenium ide, i would suggest to use both.